# Magento: Increase max_execution_time for SOAP calls only?

Tags: php, magento, soap

In a Magento system, I have a global `max_execution_time` set to 60 seconds for PHP requests. However, this limit is not enough for some calls to the SOAP API. What I would like to do is increase the execution time to say 10 minutes for API requests, without affecting the normal frontend pages.

## How can I increase max_execution_time for Magento SOAP requests only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## For Apache

This can be configured in your vhost with a `<LocationMatch "/api/">` node. Place max execution time inside that node (along with any other rules such as max memory) and they will only be applied to requests that hit /api/.*

## For Nginx

In Nginx, you should be able to accomplish the same thing with:

```
location ~ ^/api {
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
}
```

Comment: this is a good idea, but unfortunately seems hard to work for my scenario - we are using nginx + php-fpm, and it looks like configuration will be a bit tricky. Should find a way to increase this limit using a class override

Comment: Just added the Nginx equivalent